# Regarding Banach algebra homomorphism

Tags: banach-algebras, ring-homomorphism

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with identity $e_A$ and let $B$ be a Banach algebra with identity $e_B$. Let $\phi:A\longrightarrow B$ be a Banach algebra homomorphism i.e $\phi$ is linear and $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$. Then is $\phi(e_A)=e_B?$

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question exactly as you asked it is no, because it could be that $\phi(x)=0$ for every $x$.

**Edit:** In the original I said that was the only counterexample. Thanks to Omno-something for pointing out that that's nonsense. A less trivial counterexample: Define $\phi:C([0,1])\to C([0,1]\cup[2,3])$ by $$\phi f(x)=\begin{cases}f(x),&(x\in[0,1]),
\\0,&(x\in[2,3]).\end{cases}$$

In fact

> > $\phi(e_A)=e_B$ if and only if there exists $x\in A$ such that $\phi(x)$ is invertible.

One direction is trivial, since $\phi_B$ is invertible.

If there exists $x$ with $\phi(x)$ is invertible then
$$e_B\phi(x)=\phi(x)=\phi(e_Ax)=\phi(e_A)\phi(x),$$which implies $\phi(e_A)=e_B$ since $\phi(x)$ is invertible.

Comment: $e_B \phi(x) = \phi(e_A)\phi(x)$ does not (on its own) imply that $\phi(e_A) = e_B$ if $\phi(x)$ fails to be invertible.  Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: In fact, it seems to me that 
$$
\phi(A) = \pmatrix{x&0\\0&0}
$$
provides a suitable counterexample in the case that $A = \Bbb C^{n \times n}, B = \Bbb C^{m \times m}$ with $m>n$

Comment: Are you assuming that $\phi(x) \in F$??

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. No, what I had in mind was that $\phi(e_A)-e_B\in F$. I don't quite follow the notation in your second comment, not that it matters.

Comment: it can be related to your example, except with $\phi:C(\{1,\dots,n\},\Bbb F) \to C(\{1,\dots,m\},\Bbb F)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, not that it matters, but the _notation_ in that comment is confused. I have no problem with what you wrote in your answer - presumably you _meant_ the same thing here.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. For instance, with $A = \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ and $B = \Bbb C^{m \times m}$ with $n < m$, we find that
$$
\phi(M) = \pmatrix{M&0\\0&0}
$$
is a suitable map for which $\phi(e_A) \neq e_B$.